# Netbeans 8.0.2 C++ Version has no Linker Options

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans

I've got a strange little problem with my Netbeans IDE. I'm trying to compile an assignment for a class and have configured everything so far according to this guide: http://eyalarubas.com/opencv-installation-on-windows-netbeans-mingw.html

My problem now is, that I cannot find a 'Linker' field in the project properties. Either I'm blind or my version is broken somehow. Has anyone experienced this problem before and can help me?

Comment: http://imgur.com/P04Hybb this is my properties window, I've created the project from existing sources (a cmakelists.txt and the basic src.cpp was given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem now is, that I cannot find a 'Linker' field in the project properties.
>
> [...]
>
> I've created the project from existing sources (a cmakelists.txt and the basic src.cpp was given)

This is a normal behaviour. Since you are using CMake, all settings according Compiler, Linker etc are done through CMake.

If you only want to add libraries, this is usually done through CMake itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the meantime I solved the problem a little less elegant way by making a new project and renaming my existing cpp accordingly. This way I could specify all needed things in the project properties

Comment: I see, but in general you should set the cmakelists.txt - this is also the more portable way.

Comment: Note: if your question is solved, please mark it by the green tick.

Comment: no, this is just an annoying behaviour of the plugin when using "project with existing sources"
it has nothing to do with cmake specifically. it is simply because the plugin can't handle non native project formats.